# Why does everyone insist on having local SVN repositories?

Tags: svn, version-control, remote-access

Can someone help me with a big question? When doing web-based application development, why does everyone insist upon creating local versions of the server environment for development? Why not just develop on a hosted server? It seems like a serious pain to try to recreate (and keep synchronized) the entire server environment locally - especially on a variety of boxes and platforms that don't match the hosted environment anyway. It seems much simpler to create a testing environment remotely and work with files in that environment via FTP.

And yet all the SVN services and tools I've found are designed to pull copies onto a given local machine, treating the remote server as a deployment.

I want to set up a remote development environment - so developers can check out their own version of the files they need into their personal file tree on the *server*. When they're done testing in their own little environment they can commit via SVN to a single staging environment, test again there, and then copy the files from development to production. Where can I find the tool to help me set up and manage something like this?

Comment: What happens when the development server goes down? All of your coders just stop working? What happens when one of your coders has a laptop and loses internet access? Should he stop working? What happens when a coder needs to change a web server configuration setting? He should ask the sysadmin to do it for him and wait?

Comment: So, you find it painful to define an environment locally (which should be done once) and to sync it with the server environment (which should happen rarely), but you don't find it painful to have to transfer files with FTP to a remote server each time you want to test a little change during development? I'd prefer to edit the file, save it, hit refresh in my browser, and see the result of the change immediately.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JB: No, actually. With my method, the developer doesn't need to take any time to set up a dev environment at all. FTP is pretty bulletproof and fast. The server goes down far less often than

Comment: Even if it's fast. It's extremely cumbersome to have to transfer files each time you modify them. And it doesn't allow working out of the usual working environment (on a train, at home, etc.)

Comment: @JB: Yes, it is painful. Server software changes all the time. Modules are installed and updated, databases change - keeping n local machines synchronized with the remote configuration is far more cumbersome.

Comment: No, FTP isn't painful. It's bulletproof and fast. With the remote method, the developer doesn't need to take any time to set up a dev environment at all.  And what good is it to see a result immediately if it doesn't work once it gets to the server?

Comment: @JB: why doesn't FTP work on a train or at home?

Comment: Then go your own way, and see if it works well. But you'll have to maintain one remote environment per developer anyway. Everything you would have to do locally, you'll have to do it remotely. I don't see why it would be simpler, but YMMV.

Comment: @cdhowie: allowing any developer get to make server-level changes that might affect an entire deployment doesn't seem like a particularly good idea.

Comment: @MichaelSattler Which is why you want each developer to have their own sandbox where they can tweak whatever settings they may have to in an environment where it won't bother anybody else if they screw it up a few times.

Comment: @MichaelSattler: because your test servers might be in your company's LAN, and not on the Internet, and because I don't have reliable connectivity on a train (if any at all). If everything is on my dev machine, I know I can work anytime, anywhere, and quickly.

Comment: @JB: I actually ran an environment like this for nine years. We managed and deployed hundreds of applications with dozens of developers on a complex server environment. It worked fantastically well. I'm just mystified by the fact that no one else seems to be doing it.